# Computing volume of cone with open set base

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $A$ be an open Jordan-measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Given the point $\textbf{p}=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $p_3>0$, let $S$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $$S=\{\textbf{x}\mid\textbf{x}=(1-t)\textbf{a}+t\textbf{p}, \textbf{a}\in A\times \{0\}, 0<t<1\}$$ Find $v(S)$, the volume of $S$, in terms of $v(A)$, the volume of $A$.

It seems like $S$ is just a cone, so the volume should be just $1/3$ times $v(A)$ times the distance from $\textbf{p}$ to $A$. But I want to prove it rigorously. The volume $v(S)$ is $\int_S 1$, and $v(A)=\int_A 1$. I'm thinking about using the change of variables, but I'm not sure what variables to change to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the third coordinate of $(1-t)\textbf{a}+t\textbf{p}$ is $tp_3$. Hence,   $S$ lies between the planes $x_3=0$ and $x_3=p_3$. For each number $h$ in this range, the intersection of the plane $x_3=h$ with $S$ is the set $$\{(1-h/p_3)\mathbf a+ (h/p_3)(p_1,p_2):\mathbf a\in A\}\times \{h\} $$
The area of the set is $(1-h/p_3)^2 |A|$ where $|A|$ is the area of $A$. By Fubini's theorem, 
$$\iiint_S 1 = \int_0^{p_3} dh \iint_{S \cap \{x_3=h\} }  1\,dx_1\,dx_2 = 
\int_0^{p_3} dh  (1-h/p_3)^2 |A| \,dh = \frac13 p_3|A|$$
Note that $p_3$ is the distance from $\mathbf p$ to the plane containing $A$, which is not necessarily the same as the distance from $\mathbf p$ to $A$.